# SAP ByDesign SOAP API - Business Object documentation and value mapping

Tags: soap, sap-business-bydesign

I am in the processing of rebuilding some integrations with an instance of SAP ByDesign via the SOAP API. While doing this I want to understand *why* the existing code is doing what it's doing. I have been following the [SAP documentation](https://api.sap.com/package/BYD?section=Artifacts) to help me along with the integration portion. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to understand some of the response data.

For example, I'm using the [QuerySalesOrderIn](https://api.sap.com/api/PSM_ISI_R_II_QUERY_SALES_ORDER_IN/documentation) request and I need to check the *CustomerRequestReleaseStatusCode*. I see in the documentation it is an instance of type *ReleaseStatusCode* and has possible values of 1-8. But how do I find out what these values represent? Is there standardized documentation for this, or is it tied to some sort of data mapping in our particular instance of SAP? If it's the latter, how would I go about finding this data mapping in our SAP instance? This is just one example, but I would like to be able to accomplish this with all Response data objects.

Using SAP Business ByDesign. I don't have experience with SAP really, and our resource for SAP isn't very available at the moment. I appreciate any guidance where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got some guidance here. Apparently in order to find out what these codes' values can be and what they mean there is an additional API endpoint called [QueryCodeListIn](https://api.sap.com/api/PSM_ISI_R_II_QUERY_CODE_LIST_IN/overview). With this API you can specify which code you would like to look up and it will return the values and descriptions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. If you are using SAP cloud app studio and if you open repository explorer and navigate to that property of a specific business object, it shows you the code list associated with that property.